# Plugin throwing TypeError after WordPress 4.5 update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm debugging a visual composer plugin that broke after I updated WordPress to 4.5 and I can't figure out why it is throwing a TypeError.

The error message in the console:

```
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.0              load-scripts.php?....
Uncaught TypeError:     $template.get is not a function     composer-view.js?ver=4.1.1.1:73
```

The only occurrences of `$template` are found in the code below. I understand that this isn't very much context to go off of but, how can I resolve this error?

```
/**
 * Convert html into correct element
 * @param html
 */
html2element: function(html) {
  var attributes = {},
    $template;
  if (_.isString(html)) {
    this.template = _.template(html);
    $template = $(this.template(this.model.toJSON()).trim());
  } else {
    this.template = html;
    $template = html;
  }
  _.each($template.get(0).attributes, function(attr) { // **errors on this line**
    attributes[attr.name] = attr.value;
  });
  this.$el.attr(attributes).html($template.html());
  this.setContent();
  this.renderContent();
},
```

Update:

It looks like this might be a problem with jQuery. WordPress 4.5 includes jQuery 1.12 which fixed a bug that allowed certain code to be run with incorrect syntax. I assume that the plugin code must have had incorrect syntax but ran nonetheless until now.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/read-this-first-wordpress-45-master-list#post-8271654

Comment: Instead of including an image of your error message, please include it as text. This will help future readers who have a similar error message find your question through search.

Comment: any success fixing this so far?

Comment: I have this error now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090595/plugin-error-after-wordpress-update

Answer (score 124, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. Turns out I was using an older version of JS composer. Updating to the newest version broke my site so I tracked down the error and updated the `html2element` function to

```
html2element: function(html) {
            var $template, attributes = {},
                template = html;
            $template = $(template(this.model.toJSON()).trim()), _.each($template.get(0).attributes, function(attr) {
                attributes[attr.name] = attr.value
            }), this.$el.attr(attributes).html($template.html()), this.setContent(), this.renderContent()
        },
```

Comment: Just in case you can't find needed file to edit, in my case it's here: `/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/js/dist/backend.min.js`

Comment: Doubling any component doesn't work with this update @Ben

Comment: @RahmanUsta doubling works for me. What is the console error?

Comment: worked. the file is situated here: /home/statingt/public_html/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/js/backend/composer-view.js

Comment: composer-view.js?ver=4.5.3:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined i get this after changing the code

Comment: TypeError: $template.get(...) is undefined
 composer-view.js:138:73

Comment: @Ben I have this error after using your code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090595/plugin-error-after-wordpress-update

Comment: @DanHastings & Apeiron, see my answer below for a fix for "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined".

Comment: I might be asking a stupid question, havent worked with WP for a while...How do I get to the js files of the composer plugin if I have no FTP access? Thanks!

Comment: The visual composer is bundled with my theme, so I did not have access to the new version. Using the fix that @Ben suggested fixed the issue for me as well.

Comment: for 4.3.4 Visual Composer users, copy his answer and relace the exisiting in composer-view.js `/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/js/backend/composer-view.js`

Comment: This not working for WP 4.7.1. Please see the @ECC-Dan solution that works fine.

Comment: This isn't meant to be just a "Thanks, me too!" comment, but rather to specifically let future readers know this worked for the Magazinly theme where the file is wp-content/themes/Magazinly/wpbakery/js_composer/assets/js/backend/composer-view.js

Comment: WPBakery Visual Composer Version 4.9 + WordPress 5.0.3 and this update in the code fixed the issue.

Answer (score 33):

I was still getting this error after trying the patch in Ben's answer: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'custom' of undefined**

So I modified the html2element in composer-view.js as follows:

```
 html2element: function(html) {
        var $template, attributes = {},
            template = html;

        $template = $(template(this.model.toJSON()).trim());
        if($template.get(0))
        {
            _.each($template.get(0).attributes, function(attr) {
            attributes[attr.name] = attr.value
        })};

        this.$el.attr(attributes).html($template.html()),
        this.setContent(),
        this.renderContent()
    },
```

Comment: Worked for me on WP 4.6 and VC 4.6. Thanks!

Comment: You guys are great.. thanks for helping to fix this issue.  It resolved it on my end as well! :)

Comment: Worked partially on WP 4.8. It's not updating the view after composer adds an element to view. Need to save the page and reload to view the component. Any fix available?

Answer (score 18):

@Ben This works perfect!

**Cause:** 
Admin was not loading the correct visual editor for js_composer plugin after updatethis plugins.

=====================================================

**Error:**

Error: TypeError: $template.get is not a function
Source File: wp-content/plugins/js_composer_salient/assets/js/dist/backend.min.js?ver=4.10
Line: 4047

=====================================================

**Solution**
Goto file  /wp-content/plugins/js_composer_salient/assets/js/dist/backend.min.js around line 4045:

======> Replace the code =====================================================

```
    html2element: function(html) {
        var $template, attributes = {};
        _.isString(html) ? (this.template = _.template(html), $template = $(this.template(this.model.toJSON(), vc.templateOptions["default"]).trim())) : (this.template = html, $template = html), _.each($template.get(0).attributes, function(attr) {
            attributes[attr.name] = attr.value
        }), this.$el.attr(attributes).html($template.html()), this.setContent(), this.renderContent()
    },
```

======> Replace with this code ========================================

```
    html2element: function(html) {
        var $template, attributes = {},
        template = html;
        $template = $(template(this.model.toJSON()).trim()), _.each($template.get(0).attributes, function(attr) {
                attributes[attr.name] = attr.value}), 
                this.$el.attr(attributes).html($template.html()), this.setContent(), 
                this.renderContent()
    },
```

Answer (score 6):

Noticed that code was not being passed into the html2element function, but did exist in the function calling it (render)

The following code has completely corrected my problems, I can load the page, add, clone, remove, etc

```js
render: function () {
   var $shortcode_template_el = $( '#vc_shortcode-template-' + this.model.get( 'shortcode' ) );
   if ( $shortcode_template_el.is( 'script' ) ) {
    var newHtmlCode =  _.template( $shortcode_template_el.html(),
            this.model.toJSON(),
            vc.templateOptions.default );
    if(!_.isString(newHtmlCode)){
     newHtmlCode = $shortcode_template_el.html();
    }
    this.html2element( newHtmlCode );
   } else {
    var params = this.model.get( 'params' );
    $.ajax( {
     type: 'POST',
     url: window.ajaxurl,
     data: {
      action: 'wpb_get_element_backend_html',
      data_element: this.model.get( 'shortcode' ),
      data_width: _.isUndefined( params.width ) ? '1/1' : params.width,
      _vcnonce: window.vcAdminNonce
     },
     dataType: 'html',
     context: this
    } ).done( function ( html ) {
     this.html2element( html );
    } );
   }
   this.model.view = this;
   this.$controls_buttons = this.$el.find( '.vc_controls > :first' );
   return this;
  },
```

Comment: works for me too and I can copy elements, but I still got this error Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .vc_teaser-btn-{{ name }}

Answer (score 4):

I'm using the theme Applay (2.1.3, a bit outdated). I've just updated WP and all the plugins to the most recent version (4.5.2) and came to this issue as well. I did not analyzed the flow of this component (js_composer), just this "broken" function (it's not really broken). I realized that this.template and $template are getting wrong object types (it needs another validation aside `_.isString(html)`). I solved it by adding a try & catch block as follows:

**ORIGINAL**

```
    html2element:function (html) {
        var attributes = {}, 
            $template;
        if (_.isString(html)) {
            this.template = _.template(html);
            $template = $(this.template(this.model.toJSON()).trim());
        } else {
            this.template = html;                                                                                                                                            
            $template = html;
        }
        _.each($template.get(0).attributes, function (attr) {
            attributes[attr.name] = attr.value;
        }); 
        this.$el.attr(attributes).html($template.html());
        this.setContent();
        this.renderContent();
    },
```

**MODIFIED**

```
    html2element:function (html) {
        var attributes = {}, 
            $template;
        if (_.isString(html)) {
            this.template = _.template(html);
        } else {
            try {
                this.template = _.template(html());                                                                                                                          
            } catch (err) {
                this.template = html;
            }   
        }   
        $template = $(this.template(this.model.toJSON()).trim());
        _.each($template.get(0).attributes, function (attr) {
            attributes[attr.name] = attr.value;
        }); 
        this.$el.attr(attributes).html($template.html());
        this.setContent();
        this.renderContent();
    },
```

Comment: This solution worked for WP 4.6.1 and Visual Composer 4.5.3

Answer (score 3):

I am using the Astra theme. This fix is 99.9 % working. For some tho, this only stops the spinning wheel, but once the page loads visual composer does not.

I made a slight change to this code (that is posted everywhere by now)

Original Astra theme code here (composer-view.js)

```
        html2element:function (html) {
        var attributes = {},
            $template;
        if (_.isString(html)) {
            this.template = _.template(html);
            $template = $(this.template(this.model.toJSON()).trim());
        } else {
            this.template = html;
            $template = html;
        }
        _.each($template.get(0).attributes, function (attr) {
            attributes[attr.name] = attr.value;
        });
        this.$el.attr(attributes).html($template.html());
        this.setContent();
        this.renderContent();
    },
```

The code that works :

```
html2element: function(html) {
    var $template, 
    attributes = {},
    template = html;
    $template = $(template(this.model.toJSON()).trim()), 
     _.each($template.get(0).attributes, function(attr) {
    attributes[attr.name] = attr.value
}); this.$el.attr(attributes).html($template.html()), this.setContent(), this.renderContent()
```

},

The main difference is located here (versus original code)

```
}); this.$el.attr
```

There is a semicolon instead of the original comma :) :

```
}), this.$el.attr
```

Cheers folks :) So

Comment: This helped me for loading some pages, but some are only loaded partially. I am now getting this error: composer-custom-views.js?ver=4.5.3:853 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'custom' of undefined. The line looks like this: var $element = $( _.template( this.buttonTemplate, { params: params }, vc.templateOptions.custom ) );

Comment: I replaced the declaration to 0, this seems to solve everything. Probably not a solid solution though...

Answer (score 1):

Well, i found the solution in this site: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/visual-composer-is-not-working

first: edit html2element:.... in in /wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/js/backend/composer-view.js

```
html2element: function(html) {
        var $template, attributes = {},
            template = html;
        $template = $(template(this.model.toJSON()).trim()), _.each($template.get(0).attributes, function(attr) {
            attributes[attr.name] = attr.value
        }), this.$el.attr(attributes).html($template.html()), this.setContent(), this.renderContent()},
```

---

second: However if you open up the frontend editor you'll have this "trim" issue on custom_views.js:101 , and line 467 of another file. I forgot the name, but I think it may be frontend_editor.js.

edit in: \wp-content\plugins\js_composer\assets\js\frontend_editor\

- frontend_editor.js
- custom_views.js

Bad code:

```
this.$controls = $( _.template( template, data, _.extend( {},
            vc.template_options,
            { evaluate: /\{#([\s\S]+?)#}/g } ) ).trim() ).addClass( 'vc_controls' );
```

Fixed code:

```
this.$controls = $( _.template( template, data, _.extend( {},
            vc.template_options,
            { evaluate: /\{#([\s\S]+?)#}/g } ) )().trim() ).addClass( 'vc_controls' );
```

third: See the black magic.

Cheers.

Comment: in salient this is just `this.$controls = $(_.template(template, data, vc.template_options).trim()).addClass('vc_controls');`

Answer (score 1):

Checkout below code for both $template.get is not a function and Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined. Worked for me.

```
html2element: function(html) {
    var $template, attributes = {},
            template = html;

        $template = $(template(this.model.toJSON()).trim());
        if($template.get(0))
        {
            _.each($template.get(0).attributes, function(attr) {
            attributes[attr.name] = attr.value
        })};

        this.$el.attr(attributes).html($template.html()),
        this.setContent(),
        this.renderContent()
}
```

Comment: This one did the trick for me! Atleast almost: I can add elements but they don't show up until page save. Atleast I'm not getting any errors on console like I did with other code changes :D

Answer (score 1):

I made this modification that works on my WP 4.8.1 (PHP7)

in the file *wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/js/backend/composer-view.js*

you must modify the *render* method :

replace this line

```
this.html2element(_.template($shortcode_template_el.html(), this.model.toJSON()));
```

by this line

```
this.html2element( $shortcode_template_el.html() );
```

It seems the _.template() function that doesn't work perfectly and doesn't return the good object, so better give the html code instead.

Comment: Works on WP 4.9.8 and PHP 7.2!

Answer (score 0):

try updating your theme. Goto Appearance>Themes, and check for an update. This resolved the issue for me automatically upon update.

The error arises when you update to WP 4.5 for me running the Nimva theme.
You have to update to 2.02 of Nimva, which allows auto updates.