# Visual Composer error in Wordpress, after updating to WP 4.5

Tags: javascript, wordpress

This is the code that is coming up with an error from the console.

```
 /**
     * Convert html into correct element
     * @param html
     */
    html2element:function (html) {
        var attributes = {},
            $template;
        if (_.isString(html)) {
            this.template = _.template(html);
            $template = $(this.template(this.model.toJSON()).trim());
        } else {
            this.template = html;
            $template = html;
        }
        _.each($template.get(0).attributes, function (attr) {
            attributes[attr.name] = attr.value;
        });
        this.$el.attr(attributes).html($template.html());
        this.setContent();
        this.renderContent();
    },
```

[it causes the page editor not to load!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qonDw.png)

[see the line where there is an error in the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ta4Ih.png)

I apologise in advance if i have broken any rules or not explained the problem in enough detail.

Please advise if possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36605420/plugin-throwing-typeerror-after-wordpress-4-5-update - also, this is not PHP so watch your tags, it is JavaScript

Comment: The error could be related to your theme too. What theme are you using.

Comment: The solutions mentioned below did not help in my case. My solution: Delete the bundled install of Visual Composer plugin (4.5.3), buy the commercial version (version 5, Cost: $35) and install that one instead.

Answer (score 1):

Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36605420/plugin-throwing-typeerror-after-wordpress-4-5-update/).

I fixed this bug by updating the `html2element` function to:

```
html2element: function(html) {
        var $template, attributes = {},
            template = html;
        $template = $(template(this.model.toJSON()).trim()), _.each($template.get(0).attributes, function(attr) {
            attributes[attr.name] = attr.value
        }), this.$el.attr(attributes).html($template.html()), this.setContent(), this.renderContent()
    },
```

in `/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/js/backend/composer-view.js`

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this!
turns out that the problem was with the theme being out of date, so i did not get to try your solution!