# visual composer $template.get(0) is undefined

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

`$template.get(0) is undefined` this is what I got when I try to add an element with visual composer, this error is different from `$template.get(0) is not a function` witch is a common more common, after some tests I found out that `template(this.model.toJSON())` in line `138` returns an empty result,so now I hope that I can find someone who can at least tell me how to edit `this.model` value

Comment: This seems to be a common issue for anyone who has updated to Wordpress 4.3 or higher. What is your current WP version.

Comment: yes exactly my wordpress version is 4.5.3 but can't modify this

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two options.

1. Update the visual composer to latest version.
2. Use FTP to edit the visual composer js file

The first option can be done through the plugins menu on your admin panel.

For the second option you need to edit and replace some JS using FTP.
You can check out the answer here [Uncaught TypeError: $template.get is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641618/uncaught-typeerror-template-get-is-not-a-function)

Hope this answers your questions.
Happy coding!

Comment: this is not the same issue it's template get undefined

Comment: Yes I had the same problem with composer and I tried this and it seemed to fix it. Have you tried updating the plugin?

Comment: I am not sure because it a project for a client

Comment: Do you have access to the wp admin panel?

Comment: What is the version of Visual composer in the plugin panel?